# How to store user based questions and answers in superscript?

Tags: node.js, keystonejs

I am working on a chat bot where multiple users(Role:owner) can add/edit/remove their questions and answers for subordinates(Role:travelers). When a traveler questions to chat bot, chat bot should only choose answers added by his User(Role:owner).

How can I do this? I want something that I will be able to store the user id corresponding to questions/answers in main.ss file.

I am using [SuperscriptJS](http://superscriptjs.com/) with Keystone and mongodb

[image]

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

User based roles and permissions are not currently available in keystone, so this is not currently possible.

However, it's very much in the pipline. To show your interest in this feature, you can upvote it on product pains: https://productpains.com/post/keystonejs/role-based-admin-system

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of core level role implementation for this.You can have your own Role system in your User model.  For detailed study you can **refer sydJS** code.sydJS is developed by he keystoneJS developers.

in sydJS at modesl/User.js  you can search for isAdmin and isVerified. Like that you can set Role there.

But I guess , you are not asking for role, Instead in your usecase  **there is a relation called owner**. such that each user of role type *travelers* has a related User called *owner*.   or something like that. For that You can set a owner field in User model.

```
 role :string,
 owner: { type: Types.Relationship, ref: 'User',filters: { role: 'owner' },many: false, index: true,},
```

Now coming to superscript, I am not expert there but, I can say that you can either create **multiple SS file (if possible )per each owner. or You can try to  create superscript topic  per each owner**.

Please feel free  to contact me on skype: sachinbhika, because I am also about to start developing chatbot next week, so by heling you I am helping myself.